# Beginner Golang sequence clarification

Tags: go

I am trying GO as a complete newbie to programming. I have a doubt in sequence inside the following code. This code scans for user input.

```
func main() {
  fmt.Print("Enter a number: \n")
  var input float64
  fmt.Scanf("%f", &input)
  output := input * 2
  fmt.Println(output)
```

But, after the string display, at the new line when I enter any number, it should just go into a buffer of some sort or become junk value. I say so, because the allocation of scanned input starts after the first line. Had it been the first or prior step, it would perfectly make sense.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The value you enter is allocated at the input memory space (using the &). The input variable is created before the scanf (line 2) so there is no problem at all with the order of your instruction. Maybe you can clarify ?

Comment: Because Go is a compiled language, it processes the code accordingly, I suppose ?